# How to turn an array of objects in to tabular data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects:-

```
[{
    "TaAddClaim": {
        "claim_id": "CL462573115516",
        "date": "2016-11-08"
    },
    "Employee": {
        "full_name": "Admin User"
    }
}, {
    "TaAddClaim": {
        "claim_id": "CL67258688282",
        "date": "2016-11-08"
    },
    "Employee": {
        "full_name": "Admin User"
    }
}, {
    "TaPassAccount": {
        "claim_id": "CL462573115516"
    },
    "0": {
        "total_expenses": "4436.00"
    }
}, {
    "TaPassAccount": {
        "claim_id": "CL67258688282"
    },
    "0": {
        "total_expenses": "3236.00"
    }
}]
```

I want to display these data in a `HTML` table. My table structure is as follows:

```
$.each(resp, function(indx, obj) {
    if (obj.TaAddClaim) {
        table += '<tr>';
        table += '<td>' + obj.TaAddClaim.claim_id + '</td>';
        table += '<td>' + obj.TaAddClaim.date + '</td>';
        table += '<td>' + obj.Employee.full_name + '</td>';
    }
});
```

Now the problem is I am unable to display the `total_expenses` data in the table.

I want to display the `total_expenses` data if the `claim_id` of `TaAddClaim` is match with the `claim_id` of `TaPassAccount`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Try thi:- var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );

Comment: Can you modify the json? The most obvious solution would be to return the data grouped as it should be grouped and not as an array of objects where different entries might be related.

Comment: you need to manipulate your array before converting it to json

Comment: FYI nothing about this has anything to do with JSON. You're working with an array of objects.

Comment: An array of objects where each object is not the same structure is devilishly harder to work with. Can you fix the broken array structure or are you stuck with it?

Answer (score 1):

Build a "map" from `claim_id` to value before iterating over the response again to render it:

```
var claimTotals = {};
$.each(resp, function(indx, obj) {
    if (obj.TaPassAccount) {
        claimTotals[obj.TaPassAccount.claim_id] = obj[0].total_expenses;
    }
});
```

You can then refer to `claimTotals[obj.TaAddClaim.claim_id]` to get the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another each loop inside of first loop, to be able to find "total_expences" for each "claim_id"

```
$.each(resp, function(indx, obj) {
    if (obj.TaAddClaim) {
        table += '<tr>';
        table += '<td>' + obj.TaAddClaim.claim_id + '</td>';
        table += '<td>' + obj.TaAddClaim.date + '</td>';
        table += '<td>' + obj.Employee.full_name + '</td>';
        $.each(resp, function(indx, obj2) {
            if(obj2.TaPassAccount){
                if(obj2.TaPassAccount.claim_id == obj.TaAddClaim.claim_id){
                    table += '<td>' + obj2['0'].total_expenses + '</td>';
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Runnable example:
https://jsfiddle.net/yuxg19c8/2/

According to Alnitak comment, in order to lower algorithm complexity, you can also do like this. First you are collecting all "total_expenses". And then just using them in your table.

```
    var claimTotalExpenses = {};
    $.each(resp, function(indx, obj) {
            if(obj.TaPassAccount){
                claimTotalExpenses[obj.TaPassAccount.claim_id] = obj['0'].total_expenses;
            }
        });

    var table = '<table>';
    $.each(resp, function(indx, obj) {
        if (obj.TaAddClaim) {
            table += '<tr>';
            table += '<td>' + obj.TaAddClaim.claim_id + '</td>';
            table += '<td>' + obj.TaAddClaim.date + '</td>';
            table += '<td>' + obj.Employee.full_name + '</td>';
            if(claimTotalExpenses.hasOwnProperty(obj.TaAddClaim.claim_id)){
                table += '<td>' + claimTotalExpenses[obj.TaAddClaim.claim_id] + '</td>';
            }
            table += '</tr>';
        }
    });
    table += '</table>';
```

Runnable example: https://jsfiddle.net/477z59oa/

Comment: Oh, that's horrible - it turns the algorithm into O(n^2) complexity instead of linear time!